# how to securely pass a related Class_id through a hidden form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations

I have a GroupCoach model, Group Coaches has_many :groups.  On my new Group form I want to pass a group_coach_id to the Group object in a hidden field so that a group gets associated with a GroupCoach without the user having to select one.

So in my Groups_Controller

```
 @group = Group.new
 @group_coach = GroupCoach.first(:order => "RAND()")
```

This will get a random GroupCoach.  and then in the new Group view I have a hidden field

```
<%= f.hidden_field @group_coach  %>
```

This obviously doesn't work 100% right.  It does pass the group_coach_id but its not telling the form what column to save it in...

I have also heard this is very insecure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a token column. Simply SHA1 encrypt it (or whatever your choice is) and pass that instead. It's much harder to guess.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code to resolve this issue

```
<%= f.hidden_field :group_coach_id, :value => @group_coach.id   %>
```

But is this the most secure? Seems pretty insecure as I could change the value in Firebug or something...